# custom Prometheus metrics is not showing up

Tags: go, prometheus, grafana

Below is how I configured the metrics when I hit /metrics endpoint i'm not able to see the metric name "http_requests_total" is there anything i'm missing

```
HttpReqs := prometheus.NewCounterVec(
        prometheus.CounterOpts{
            Name: "http_requests_total",
            Help: "How many HTTP requests processed, partitioned by status code and HTTP method.",
        },
        []string{"code", "method"},
    )

    prometheus.MustRegister(HttpReqs)
```